# How to add/get the internal application data?

Tags: android, file-io

If i have a file in /data/data//files/data.dat, how to get the data.dat file ?
To get it i maked this:

```
File f1 = new File("data/data/carburant.android.com/files/data.dat");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
```

I know it's not 100% coorect ? how to correct it? and how to add a file in this path?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1: Call [`openOutputStream("data.dat");`](http://goo.gl/xziPw)

Option #2: Call `new File(getFilesDir(), "data.dat");` to use [`getFilesDir()`](http://goo.gl/TkDqi)

Option #3: Call [`getFileStreamPath("data.dat");`](http://goo.gl/SBdav)

Comment: And please how to add a new file in "data/data/carburant.android.com/files/" ?

Comment: @androniennn: Any of the three options in my answer will give you a `File` or an `OutputStream`. From there, you use normal Java I/O.